# Action bar menu layout

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

I am using [ActionbarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to implement action bar for Android 2.1 API 7 platform. The Sherlock library is imported to my own project successfully.

Then, in my project, I have `res/menu/action_menu.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/test1"
          android:title="@string/test_1"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          />    
    <item android:id="@+id/test2"
          android:title="@string/test_2"
          android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
          />
</menu>
```

My Activity:

```
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.Menu;
import android.support.v4.view.MenuItem;

public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity {

     @Override
     protected void onStart() {
      super.onStart();
      ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();

      actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
      actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

      }

      ...

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
      inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);
      return true;
    }
}
```

With the above code, My application has an action bar. **But the problem is** that all the items defined in the above menu xml file are showing on the **right hand side** of the action bar, and the left side part of action bar is left **blank**.

You probably already noticed in my Activity code, I have:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
```

The above two line codes are defined in my **Activity** `onStart()` callback which disable the action bar default text and icon.

But how can I have my custom items defined in menu xml file to be shown **evenly** on the action bar instead of only show on the right hand side of the action bar?

Comment: To start you should use Sherlock classes : SerlockFragmentActivity ...etc  maybe take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11264808/android-action-bar-with-two-stretched-buttons