# Trying to set up custom Actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to set up a custom actionbar mimicking the Google calendar actionbar based on Simon Jackson's answer to an SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15103895/cancel-done-buttons-in-calendar-app-is-it-part-of-action-bar).

However, I'm struggling with 'mContext' as I don't know what context it is referring to.

There are 2 instances of mContext, 1 when inflating the View and 2 when instantiating the actionbar.  I've tried both the application context and inflater context but although each works for one mContext instance, neither works for both.

In the context of this code fragment, what is mContext?

I'm developing using Android Studio and API 22.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

mContext would be referencing the:

```
getApplicationContext()
```

call from the Activity

Comment: Thanks.  The reason it wasn't working for the actionbar is because I'd imported android.app,actionbar rather than android.support.v7.Actionbar and android.support.v7..app.AppCompatActivity.

Comment: No problem :) right, those auto-imports get you sometimes with the v7 vs v7.appcompat versions

Answer (score 0):

Add this before you call `onCreate()`:

```
Context mContext;
```

Or preferably as suggested above,replace `mContext` with `getApplicationContext()`